# Minecraft update from 1.16.4 to 1.17 java error occurs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

i have minecraft version 1.16.4 on my pc. OS is windows 10. today I wanted to get new major update. when i run the launcher i got the error that said "minecraft does not detect java". so i uninstalled minecraft and java. i installed them again. but now after update i get this java error:

```
   [E] Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
   [E] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
   net/minecraft/client/main/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java 
   Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class 
   file versions up to 52.0
```

what should i do to fix this? (if any further information is needed please comment so i add them to my question)

minecraft launcher is ExtremeLauncher 3.9.5.0. i have javaRE 8.291 and javaDK 16 installed on my pc.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that may face this problem, you should change java address in your launcher to something like this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\javaw.exe`

Browse your pc for the right address before changing.

Comment: Another option (for those who can't change the Java location from the launcher) is to add Java to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: On MultiMC in macOS, I had to install JDK 16 (as per [this page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html)) and then set my instance to use `/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` as the Java binary under the instance's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall or disable (under control panel-java) JRE, then install JDK again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).